# Is there a way to store transformed xml withing xslt template or variable etc and then use it for further processing?

Tags: xml, xslt, tree, transformation

Is there a way to store transformed xml withing XSLT template or variable etc and then use it for further processing? Transformed xml will have different elements (count and names) and I need to process them within the same stylesheet to produce final transformed XML.

I'm trying to solve following problem.

STARTING XML

```
<shop>

    <product>
        <name />
        <categorytxt> Garden > Tables > Blue </categorytxt>
    </product>

    <product>
        <name/>
        <categorytxt> Garden > Tables > Green </categorytxt>
    </product>
     
    
    <product>
        <name />
        <categorytxt> Home > Tables > Green </categorytxt>
    </product>

    <product>
        <name />
        <categorytxt> Home > Chairs > White </categorytxt>
    </product>

</shop>
```

And my desired output XML would be this...

```
<!-- category treeview structure -->
<categories>
    <category id="1" parent="root">Garden</category>
    <category id="2" parent="1">Tables</category>
    <category id="3" parent="2">Blue</category>
    <category id="4" parent="2">Green</category>

    <category id="5" parent="root">Home</category>
    <category id="6" parent="5">Tables</category>
    <category id="7" parent="6">Green</category>

    <category id="8" parent="5">Chairs</category>
    <category id="9" parent="8">White</category>
</categories>
```

So far I was only able to filter unique categorytxt elements and
split them up into  category elements

But the problem is how to filter out duplicates (can't have more than one 'Home' in result xml etc.) and assigning correct id and parent to the elements. Any ideas how to solve this?

This is the working code in progress so far

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="no" method="xml" />


<xsl:template match="/">

        

        
        <categories>

            <xsl:for-each select="//categorytxt[not(.=../../preceding-sibling::categorytxt/product)]">

                <xsl:sort select="." />

                <!-- try to save it to the parameter variable whatever -->
                <!-- splits each row into elements -->
                 
                    <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">

                        
                        <xsl:with-param name="num" select="1" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="concat(. ,' > ')" />
                          
                    </xsl:call-template>
               

            </xsl:for-each>

        </categories>

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="output-tokens">

    
    <xsl:param name="num" />
 
    <xsl:param name="list" />
    <xsl:variable name="newlist" select="concat(normalize-space($list), ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, '>')" />
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newlist, '>')" />

   

    <xsl:if test="$first">
        
         <category id="{$num}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space($first)" />
         </category>
       
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
        <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">
            <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes you can store XML generated by your transformation inside a variable and reference it in subsequent steps. As to your logic for your desired output, it's really not clear how your input transforms into your stated output.

Comment: Hard to tell how to fix your code without seeing it. Especially when we don't even know which version of XSLT you're using.

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.    And I do not know how to xpath resulting categories/category for further processing

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are we talking about?

Comment: so far testing in chrome <?xml-stylesheet href="xsl10.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

Comment: I meant which processor will you be using in production. You have quite a task in front of you and you could benefit from several extension functions, if your processor supports them. --- I would also recommend you learn about Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Thank you Michael. This is also useful information about grouping. Now I have a fighting chance with the information provided by you and Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, in XSLT 1, if you create nodes in a variable/parameter e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="intermediary-result-rtf">
  <foo>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </foo>
</xsl:variable>
```

that variable is of type result tree fragment on which standard/pure XSLT 1.0 only allows `xsl:copy-of select="$intermediary-result-rtf` or `xsl:value-of select="$intermediary-result-rtf"`.

However, most XSLT 1.0 processors support an extension function (in a proprietary namespace or in the EXSLT namespace `http://exslt.org/common`) to convert a result tree fragment into a node-set e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="intermediary-result"
  select="exsl:node-set($intermediary-result-rtf)"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>
```

then you can select e.g. `$intermediary-result/foo`, i.e. do XPath selections on the node-set.

Comment: This is a good starting point. Thank you.