# How I can save in variable xml fragment and use it in <apply-templates>?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

XML

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT version 1

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <xsl:variable name="var">
    <content>
      <xsl:copy-of select="cd"/>
    </content>
  </xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$var"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I expect that the $var variable contains xml of the format:

```
<content>
  <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
</content>
```

I want the processing to continue on the template <xsl:template match="content">

I don't understand how this can be achieved.

Comment: See whether https://stackoverflow.com/a/74520931/252228 helps. Or move to XSLT 2 or 3, with Saxon Java, Saxon .NET, SaxonC and SaxonJS there are plenty of options on different platforms.

Comment: Why don’t you make a template that match «cd» that contains the code you have in your xsl:variable ?